# Thermodynamic System Linked To Outdoors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I have a problem that I'm having a tough time approaching. The question is:

> "Given a volume $V$ linked to the outdoors through a small hole, with pressure outside $P$, determine the energy required to heat from $T_1$ to $T_2$".

My approach has been to assume $V$ and $P$ to be constant, but allow $N$ and $T$ to vary. With this being the case I get $$PV = C$$ $$\implies N_1 k T_1 = N_2 k T_2$$  $$\implies N_1 T_1 = N_2 T_2$$ Then I try to write the energy by heating as:
$$Q = \Delta E + W$$ $$\implies \Delta E = \frac{3}2 k \Delta(NT)$$ $$\implies \frac{3}2 k (\Delta N T + N \Delta T)$$

This is the point at which I think my approach is not correct, because I can't simultaneously hold N andT constant while they are both changing in the problem. Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you learning about the open system (control volume) version of the first law of thermodynamics?

Comment: @ChetMiller This is a question from an old multi-subject exam I'm using to study from (which has no solutions), so unfortunately there is really no context such as that which I'm aware of.

Comment: OK.  Let me ask my question a little differently.  Are you familiar with the open system version of the first law of thermodynamics (which is necessary to correctly solve this problem)?

Comment: I have submitted this problem to PhysicsForums.com to see what people come up with there (even though I have already solved this correctly myself).  So, if you want to see the solution to this problem, go there.  If no one succeeds in solving it correctly there, I will flesh out the solution.

Comment: See the complete solution to this problem here:  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/thermodynamics-constant-pressure-tank-heating-problem.999049/#post-6451156

Answer (score 1):

To get you started on this problem, the open system version of the first law of thermodynamics applied to this system reads as follows:  $$d(nu)=dQ+hdn$$where n is the number of moles of gas in the volume during the process, u is the internal energy per mole of the gas in the volume, and h is the enthalpy per mole of gas in the volume.  hdn represents the enthalpy of gas stream leaving the volume during the process.  I hope that this is enough of a hint.